# How to split a file to several parts, write those parts to disk and join them back with node js stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

My goal is to create a node script for downloading using multiple
connections. So, I plan to create a multiple request with range header,
pipe the response stream to several parts, and then join all of them
into single file when every connections is done downloading.

I'm not sure how to join those file parts. To make sure, i try write
a half of file and write it with this:

```
const fs      = require('fs');

const input   = 'video.mp4';
const output1 = 'video.mp4.part1';

const half    = fs.statSync(input).size / 2;

const rstream = fs.createReadStream(input);
const part1 = fs.createWriteStream(output1);

part1
  .write(rstream.read(half));
```

But, there's an error happen:

`TypeError: May not write null values to stream`

I guess it's because the file not ended properly. So, how to do this
(split and join a file back) correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the boundaries of the readable stream you create by providing  the options

```
{start , end}
```

. This will allow you to stream just the part you want to read from your original file.

You can simply add a listener to the data event and store the chunks into your writable stream.

here's the concept and you can build on it.

```
const fs      = require('fs');
const path    = require ('path');
const input   = 'video.mp4.zip';
const output1 = 'video.mp4.zip.part1';
const half    = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname ,input)).size / 2;

const rstream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname ,input),
    {
        start : 0,
        end : half,
        autoClose: true
    }
);
writable = fs.createWriteStream(output1);
rstream.on ('data', (chunk) => {
    writable.write (chunk);
});
```

When reading the second part of the file, create your readable stream starting from the "half" position

```
const rstream2 = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname ,input), 
    {
        start : half,
        autoClose: true 
    }
);
```

Also remember when combining the files back together, to specify the start position of your writable stream as well.

#### edit to add the combine code

As per the comment request, here is the combine method

```
const output   = 'combined.zip';
const input1 = 'video.mp4.zip.part1';
const input2 = 'video.mp4.zip.part2';
const file1Size =  fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname ,input1)).size;
const file2Size = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname ,input2)).size;

const writable = fs.createWriteStream(output, {
  emitClose : true,
  autoClose: true
});
fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname ,input1), {
  autoClose : true
}).pipe(writable);

const writable2 = fs.createWriteStream(output, {
  start : file1Size,
  end : file2Size,
  autoClose: true
});
fs.createReadStream(input2, {
  autoClose: true
}).pipe(writable2);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Can you please say how to combine the files back together.

Comment: @Jeyanth yes sure I will add edit the answer with the combine code based on the above

Comment: @Mohammed Abbas Thanks! for the edit. However it does not work for my case. Have a look at my code https://codeshare.io/GAo1mr . Hope I get some solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jeyanth I’ll take a look in the morning and check what’s happening. Sorry I’ve been away the last two days

Comment: @Jeyanth, I have checked your code and the problem could be with how you're splitting your files. I've created a split.js and a combine.js code for you so you can build on :) https://codeshare.io/aYYJBY

Comment: This answer gave me some valuable information. I managed to finish a chunked file upload handler with this. :) I had problems with corrupted files before finding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can split and merge file parts easily with [node-split-file](https://github.com/tomvlk/node-split-file).

Here is a full working example of merging:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const splitFile = require('split-file');
const names = ["video.mp4.part1", "video.mp4.part2"];

splitFile.mergeFiles(names, __dirname + 'video.mp4')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Done!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  });
```